# Combine layer styles to multiple UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have these 4 lines to append a shadow to a UIButton:

```
option1Label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
option1Label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
option1Label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
option1Label.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
```

But I also have 4 different buttons, which would result in repeating myself for every button and just change the number in `option1Label`.

Maybe a dumb example, but in CSS it would look like this to apply the same style to multiple elements:

```
.element1,
.element2,
.element3 {
    color: #121212;
}
```

Is there any way in Swift 4 to combine these 4 buttons and apply them all at once to these 4 lines of styles?

**UPDATE:**

A bit more code to see what's going on. The 4 buttons are also IBOutlets, because they need to change the text at some point:

```
@IBOutlet weak var option1Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var option2Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var option3Label: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var option4Label: UIButton!
```

IBAction:

```
@IBAction func answerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pickedAnswer = sender.tag
    questionNumber += 1
}
```

Comment: Actually, in CSS you should create one class shared by all 3 buttons. And the same can be done in Swift. You can define a class (subclass of UIButton) and handle styling there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either subclass `UIButton` and add the shadow there or do something like this:

```
let option1Label = UIButton()
let option2Label = UIButton()
let option3Label = UIButton()
let option4Label = UIButton()

[option1Label, option2Label, option3Label, option4Label].forEach { button in
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
}
```

The label / button naming confuses me btw... :)

Comment: I updated my question so you can hopefully see a bit more of whats going on. Trying your snipped caused some errors in Xcode: "Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'layer'".

Comment: The same way you provided, just changed the "button" to my naming of "answerButton".

Comment: Then the error message does not make any sense... can you paste your code?

Comment: It is working now. I needed to add it like that: "answerButton?.layer ..." So your code worked, I just needed to apply a "?" after the button declaration.

Comment: Still confuses me. But glad I could help. :)